# iOS (sim) file binary read gives gibberish at the end

Tags: ios, file, memory, binary

I use this routine to do a binary read from file to memory, which worked fine until now... on iOS at least, in the simulator(...don't have the paid developer program(yet ;) ))

The numbers e.g. fileSize, bytesRead are OK, but it gives gibberish at the end...

I can't have overwritten memory, since I do the output right away...

Then I thought it could be an alignment boundary issue e.g. fileSize % 4 = det. gibberish.
But that would be strange behavior, the function gets a size and a count, the lib should calc a multiple byte read on the background, so that shouldn't cause the problem...

Here's the code I use:

```
uint8_t *readFileToMemory(FILE *fp)
{
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    long fileSize = ftell(fp);
    rewind(fp);
    //
    printf("fileSize %lu bytes\n",fileSize);
    //
    uint8_t *fileData = NULL;
    //
    fileData = (uint8_t *)requestMemory(fileData, (MEM_TYPE_MEMSIZE)fileSize, BF_MEM_ZERO_NO, "readFileToMemory()");
    fread(fileData, 1, (size_t)fileSize, fp);
    //
    long sizeRead = fread(fileData, 1, (size_t)fileSize, fp);
    printf("sizeRead %lu bytes\n",sizeRead);
    //
    fclose(fp);
    //
    printf("+\n+\nfileData:\n%s+\n+\n",fileData);
    //
    return fileData;
}
```

The reason why I post this question is "WHY the gibberish?" on iOS-sim, I do have a simple workaround btw...

Niels

Comment: What do you mean "gibberish"?  What are you expecting to see?  Binary data sure looks like gibberish to me, even if it is not.  This method is too complicated anyway...unless you need portability you should use the simple workaround you have.  I assume you are asking this question purely because you are curious and not because you need to get it to work.

Comment: I can't answer my own question within 8 hours?

Comment: Here it is: I realized my workaround is the right thing to do.
The shader file, a raw-text file, isn't NULL-terminated as printf() as well as glCompileShader() expects... Oops ;)


Niels

Comment: @borrrden: 'this method is too complicated anyway...' is that your final thought ;)

Comment: You could also use `NSData` and collapse all of that logic into one line.  You can still get access to the underlying byte array for glCompileShader()

Comment: @borrrden I have to admit, yet the cocoa-libs feel very unfamiliar and my C-method can't be much simpler, so basically I still can't judge how right you are... :) However I did notice some very cumbersome, redundancy seeing others using cocoa-libs 'how it should be used...' e.g. to open a simple png, you have to alloc the memory more than once, via a UIImage blablabla createbitmap etcetc.... I have seen people using dictionary even in books, that I thought the only reason can be delaying the program... ;)

Comment: `[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:]` will get you the binary of any file that you can find on the file system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am here now, so I might as well provide an answer for closure ;)

I forgot to put an '\0' at the end of the binary file before passing it along as (c/glsl NULL-terminated)string... Oops :)

I thank borrrden for his remarks on the Apple libs binary-read, which I still need to look into... (time time time)

Niels